# How to properly add "handleOpenURL" method on iPhone App Delegate

Tags: iphone, delegates

I am pretty new to objective-c.
I am working on a Video App. I am trying to connect my App with Facebook.
I am trying to make the "Single Sign On" to work. The flow seems to be working fine:

1. Facebook App is loaded.
2. I press "Allow" or "Don't Allow" and my App is being put to foreground.

But, for some reason I cannot make the "handleOpenURL" to work. I followed Facebook instructions and added this method to my class: AVCamViewController (this class is taken from the AVFoundation example App):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {    
NSLog(@"Facebook handleOpenURL");
return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
```

}

The method is never called.
I guess I am doing something wrong related with the App delegate.
The problem, I don't know exactly what is App delegate and how can I access it?

Can anyone help me to properly use the "handleOpenURL" in my App?

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: You need to implement the [handleOpenURL: method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:) in your [application delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW32)

Comment: @albertamg has the correct solution; he should make it the answer so we can vote for it.

Comment: @Rob Napier I followed your advise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleOpenURL:` method is part of the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3ahandleOpenURL%3a) protocol. You need to implement this method in your [application delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW32).

Comment: That's the problem, it looks like I don't have an App delegate. I used AVCam sample project as a basis for my Application. I want to make the class: AVCamViewController my App Delegate, but have no idea how it can be done.

Comment: Create a new class and make it conform to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol like this: `@interface AVCamAppDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>`. Open your main nib file (typically "MainWindow.xib") and drag an NSObject from the Library. Open the Inspector and change the class identity to your class name. Then wire the delegate outlet: ctrl-click on the File's Owner and select the object. A pop up window captioned "Outlets" shows up. Click "delegate". This is it.